# How to detect difference between refresh and back button in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, back

I used this block of code to delete sessionStorage upon page refresh.

```
if (window.performance) { 
   if (performance.navigation.type == 1) { 
      sessionStorage.removeItem("rowsCache"); 
   } 
}
```

It works, however, window.performance throws undefined on mac safari 9.
Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Store a value in session storage when the user visits for the first time :)

```
function f()
        {
          if(typeof sessionStorage != 'undefined'){
            if(!sessionStorage.getItem('visited')){ //first time visiting
                sessionStorage.setItem('visited',true);
            }else{ //refresh
              sessionStorage.removeItem("rowsCache");
            }
           }
        }
```

Another option:

```
function unload() {
     sessionStorage.removeItem("rowsCache");
}

window.onbeforeunload = unload;
```

Comment: Tried it but it still delete my sessionStorage upon clicking back button. What I want is when the user refresh, it deletes the sessionStorage but when the user navigates to another page and then clicked the back, the sessionStorage should still be there